# While loop that exit when the condition is met

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to write a while loop in bash script that does exit when the process is ended successfully what I have tried so far is;

```
VAR=`ps -ef |grep -i tail* |grep -v grep |wc -l`
while true; do
{
if [ $VAR = 0 ]
then
echo "Sending MAils ...."
exit
fi
}
done
```

Comment: You set `VAR` before entering the loop, and you never change it afterwards. This means that either the condition `[ $VAR = 0 ]` is met on the first iteration, and the script exits immediately, or the condition is not met, and the loop runs forever.

Comment: Add any information that can help, like what `tail` commands you are running and the output of `ps -ef |grep -i tail* |grep -v grep`.

Answer (score 0):

use `break` instead of `exit` to continue the execution of your script.

Also, there is no need for `{`.

Comment: But also, `VAR` doesn't change inside the loop, so either you have a no-op or an endless loop.

Comment: yeah, just mentioned the answer to the question, the script has multiple errors :)

Answer (score 0):

Your script has numerous errors. Probably try https://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

You need to update the value of the variable inside the loop.

You seem to be reinventing `pgrep`, poorly.

(The regular expression `tail*` looks for `tai`, `tail`, `taill`, `tailll` ... What do you actually hope this should do?)

To break out of a loop and continue outside, use `break`.

The braces around your loop are superfluous. This is shell script, not C or Perl.

You are probably looking for something like

```
while true; do
   if ! pgrep tail; then
      echo "Sending mails ...."
      break
   fi
done
```

This avoids the use of a variable entirely; if you do need a variable, [don't use upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

---

Based on information in comments, if you have a number of processes like

```
tail -2000f /var/log/log.{1..10}
```

and no way to check their PIDs any longer, you might want to use `fuser` to tell you when none of them are running any longer:

```
while true; do
    fuser /var/log/log.{1..10} || break
    sleep 60
done
echo All processes are gone now.
```

Unfortunately, `fuser` does not reliably set its exit code - test on the command line (run `tail -f $HOME/.bash_profile` in one window and then `fuser $HOME/.bash_profile && echo yes` in another; then quit the `tail` and run `fuser` again. If it still prints `yes` you need something more.)

On MacOS, I found that `fuser -u` will print parentheses when the files are still open, and not when not:

```
while true; do
    fuser -u /var/log/log.{1..10} 2>&1 | grep -q '[()]' || break
    sleep 60
done
```

On Debian, `fuser` is in the package `psmisc`, and does set its exit code properly. You will probably also want to use the `-s` option to make it run quietly.

Notice also the addition of a `sleep` to avoid checking hundreds or thousands of times per second. You would probably want to make the same change to the original solution. How long to wait between iterations depends on how urgently you need the notification, and how heavy the operation to check the condition is. Even `sleep 0.1` would be a significant improvement over the sleepless spin lock.

Comment: The issue is I have multi "tail -2000f /var/log/log.{1..10}" that are running in the background and I want to wait untill they ended regardless how. and eventually this command "VAR=`ps -ef |grep -i tail* |grep -v grep |wc -l`"  will return 0 which means all process's that start with tail are ended and I want to set a loop until this condition is met. How can I do It?

Comment: If this answer doesn't work. it's probably because you have other unrelated `tail` processes running. Probably a better solution is to check with `fuser` whether some process is holding an open file handle to the log files.

Comment: The `-f` option tells `tail` to never end, so what are you hoping for? And running tail on the background 10 times? Where will `tail` write it's output?

Comment: I updated the answer to show a sketch of a `fuser` solution.